# What is the language on this bracelet?

Tags: written-language

[image]I found this silver bracelet in the early 1950's and cannot identify the language, even after checking several help sites on the internet.

Comment: Looks like Han characters, so Chinese, Japanese, etc?

Answer (score 3):

It's Chinese, and it should be read from right to left as "阿弥陀佛".

This is probably the most widely used phrase, in my own layman opinion, in Buddhism. When visiting a Chinese monastery, you are likely to be greeted with a devout "阿弥陀佛" by monks with their palms put together.

Comment: How do you pronounce that? What is the pinyin?

Comment: @Mitch [ē mí tuó fó] The pronunciation of "阿" in "阿弥陀佛" is different from that in other circumstances. Instead of common "ā", it is "ē".

Comment: And this [ē mí tuó fó] is the Chinese pronounciation of the Sanskrit [_Amitābha, Amida_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitābha#Names_in_various_languages), a celestial buddha according to the scriptures of Mahāyāna Buddhism. 佛 [fó] means 'Buddha', so [ē mí tuó fó] is 'Buddha Amida'.